# Adding margin causes sister-elements to have the same margin

Tags: html, css

I have made this centered navigation bar, and I wanted to add a `:active` state to the link by making it look like it's pressed so I added a `margin-top:2px` on the `a` element.

```
<ul>
    <li>Previous</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

The problem is why are the other `a` elements also have a margin-top even if I only assigned it to the element that is currently being clicked?

---

```
ul {
    text-align:center;
}
li {
    color:#555+60;
    display:inline;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:0 4px;
}
li:first-child,li:last-child {
    border:1px solid #bbb;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#555;
}
a:active {
    margin-top:2px;
}​
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pxmp3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually adding a margin to all `a` elements, rather this is the way inline-block elements behave given their line-height, vertical alignment etc.

You are rendering `li` elements inline. Picture a baseline going through them - now, when you end up pushing a child of one of the nodes down 2px it *cannot* disturb this baseline so it ends up pushing this baseline in a uniform manner, visually bringing down the rest of the buttons.

I'd suggest avoiding non-trivial usage of `inline-block` until you are comfortable with its rendering specifics - try, for instance, [floating](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxmp3/1/) or using [position:relative](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxmp3/2/)

Comment: the `position:relative` was effective. Thank you for helping.